# Wrong increment and decrement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

As it's understandable from the code, I'm trying to create a simple img gallery.

I'm currently facing a calculation problem; if you run the snippet performing these actions you'll see what's wrong in the console log:

1. clicking on an img you'll get the id of the current clicked id
2. if you click **next** the first number it prints out is the same of the clicked id
3. but if you click now **prev** you'll see that actually the value was correct 'cause it prints the incremented number and you need to clicks to decrement
4. if you click now on another img you'll get the id of the new clicked div
5. but if you click now **prev** or **next** it performs the increment or decrement two times and it seems as the previous variable `$ph_id` is not overwritten by the new id

Can someone please explain me where the problem comes from? 'Cause I thought the code was written right but apparently I'm missing something.

[**EDIT**] I put the `$('#next').click(function ()` and the `$('#prev').click(function ()` outside of the `$('.venus-div').click(function ()` and the problem at points 4. and 5. are now solved

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('.venus-div').click(function () {
            $this       = $(this);
            $ph_id      = $this.attr('id');
            console.log('Current id: ' + $ph_id);
        });
        
        $('#next').click(function () {
                $next_id    = $ph_id++;
                console.log('Next id: ' + $next_id);
        });
        
        $('#prev').click(function () {
                $prev_id    = $ph_id--;
                console.log('Prev id: ' + $prev_id);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="venus-div" id="1" data-image="../img/bv.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/bv_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-div" id="2" data-image="../img/islamuj.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/islamuj_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-div" id="3" data-image="../img/vertical.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/vertical_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <div class="venus-div" id="4" data-image="../img/pano.jpg">
        <img src="../img/thumb/pano_thumb.jpg" class="venus-thumb">
    </div>
    <p id="prev">BACK</p>
    <p id="next">NEXT</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$next_id = $ph_id++;` sets `$next_id` to the current value of `$ph_id` and *then* increments `$ph_id` by one. If you want the increment to happen first, you can place the `++` *before* the variable like so:

```
$next_id = ++$ph_id;
```

With this, `$next_id` will be equal to the incremented `$ph_id`.

The same applies to `--`:

```
$prev_id = --$ph_id;
```

Comment: I totally ignored that but it makes sense. Thanks James, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are creating and binding every click a new click event in next and prev, and its triggering multiple times due to this multiple binding. You can either off these events or bind them outside the venus-div click function (making ph_id, next_id and prev_id global vars inside document ready.

I cant write coding from mobile, if you need i'll update it later :)